# ORACLE - UPDATE each row conditionally (iterate table only once)

Tags: oracle, sql-update, conditional-statements, case

I have the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EPS_PROPOSAL 
WHERE NSF_CODE = 14 OR
      NSF_CODE =  5 OR
      NSF_CODE =  3 OR
      NSF_CODE = 45 OR
      NSF_CODE = 11 OR
      NSF_CODE =  2 OR
      NSF_CODE =  7 OR
      NSF_CODE = 46 OR
      NSF_CODE = 37 OR
      NSF_CODE = 22 OR
      NSF_CODE = 40 OR
      NSF_CODE =  9 OR
      NSF_CODE = 47 OR
      NSF_CODE = 19 OR
      NSF_CODE = 13 OR
      NSF_CODE =  4 OR
      NSF_CODE = 48 OR
      NSF_CODE = 42 OR
      NSF_CODE = 49 OR
      NSF_CODE = 50 OR
      NSF_CODE = 31 OR
      NSF_CODE = 27 OR
      NSF_CODE = 10 OR
      NSF_CODE = 41 OR
      NSF_CODE = 39 OR
      NSF_CODE = 35 OR
      NSF_CODE = 21;

1   COUNT(*) = 902
```

Now, if I attempt to iterate through the EPS_PROPOSAL table with the following UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE EPS_PROPOSAL
SET NSF_CODE = (CASE WHEN NSF_CODE = 14 THEN 3
                     WHEN NSF_CODE =  5 THEN 4
                     WHEN NSF_CODE =  3 THEN 5
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 45 THEN 7
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 11 THEN 8
                     WHEN NSF_CODE =  2 THEN 9
                     WHEN NSF_CODE =  7 THEN 11
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 46 THEN 12
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 37 THEN 13
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 22 THEN 14
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 40 THEN 41
                     WHEN NSF_CODE =  9 THEN 19
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 47 THEN 20
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 19 THEN 21
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 13 THEN 2
                     WHEN NSF_CODE =  4 THEN 22
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 48 THEN 23
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 42 THEN 24
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 49 THEN 25
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 50 THEN 27
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 31 THEN 29
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 27 THEN 31
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 10 THEN 34
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 41 THEN 35
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 39 THEN 37
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 35 THEN 38
                     WHEN NSF_CODE = 21 THEN 39 END);    

1,866 rows updated.
```

It appears that my UPDATE statement iterated through my table more than once to get the job done, but I am trying to go through the table 1 row at a time and update each row if it meets one of the conditions - otherwise, I will overwrite something that I previously updated.

Bottom line - I should only see 902 rows updated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How many rows in your table? 1866 or 902?

Comment: @APC - 1,866.  Good call.  I didn't think to check how many records I had.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem does not appear to be that the table is being read multiple times.  Your `UPDATE` statement does not have a `WHERE` clause so it will update every row in the table regardless of the `nsf_code` value.  If you want to update a subset of rows, you'll need to include a `WHERE` clause

```
UPDATE eps_proposal
   SET nsf_code = (CASE ...)
 WHERE nsf_code IN (14,5,3,...,21)
```